# ¡Como puedo pasar multiples parametros opcionales para realizar filtrado usando Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

Teniendo dos componentes, Componete1 y Componente2:
en Componente1 intento hacer esto:

Componente1.razor

```
public string Marca
public string Modelo
public int Año
public string Tipo

NavigationManager.NavigateTo("lista-articulo/" + Marca + "/" + Modelo + "/" +Año + "/" + Tipo )
```

En Componente 2 Intento hacer esto:

Componente2.razor

```
@page"Lista-autos/{Marca}/{Modelo}/{Año}/{tipo}"

@code{
    [Parameter] public string Marca { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Modelo { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public int Año { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Tipo { get; set; }
}

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
     Result = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<SearchResponse>("api/Search/" + Marca +"/" Modelo +"/" + Año +"/" + Tipo);
}
```

De esta forma funciona si paso todos los parametros a la vez pero y en ese orden. ¿ Como le hago para pasar del Componente1 al Componente2 Solo 1 o 2 0 3. Por ejemplo Marca y Año, o, Modelo y Tipo. O quizas solo Año. Ya intente de esta forma:

```
@page"Lista-autos/{Marca}"
@page"Lista-autos/{Modelo}"...
@page"Lista-autos/{Marca}/{Modelo}/..."`
```

Pero no es posible al ser del mismo tipo(string)
Intente tambien usando AspNetCore.WebUtilities de esta forma:

```
        var query = new Uri(NavigationManager.Uri).Query;

        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(query).TryGetValue("Marca", out var value1))
        {
            Marca = value1;
        }

        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(query).TryGetValue("Modelo", out var value2))
        {
            Modelo = value2;
        }
        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(query).TryGetValue("Marca", out var value3))
        {
            Año = Convert.ToInt32(value3);
        }

        if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(query).TryGetValue("Modelo", out var value4))
        {
            Tipo = value4;
        }
        Result = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<SearchResponse>("api/Search/" + Marca +"/" Modelo +"/" + Año +"/" + Tipo);
```

Pero esta claro que no lo estoy haciendo bien porque no me funciona. ¿ Alguien sabe como enviar parametros opcionales para realizar un filtrado usando blazor?

Comment: ¿Una opción válida sería enviar los parámetros, pero vacíos? - algo así como: `Modelo=&Año=2020&Tipo=` - generando así que los parámetros sean opcionales...

Answer (score 0):

1. En caso que quieres seguir usando el metodo GET para pasar parametros:
   Siempre pasar todos los parametros, pero tener previsto un caso que sea nulo y asi no apliacar este parametro. Ejemplo:

   string link = "lista-articulo/" + "" + "/" + "" + "/" + "" + "/" + Tipo;

Al recoger los parametros verifica el valor:

```
bool applyFilterMarca = false;
if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Marca))
{
   applyFilterMarca = true;
}
```

Luego utilizas este conocimiento para aplicar el filtro.

2. Segunda opción en lugar de rutas puedes utilizar metodo POST y olvidar de este problema. En el Post tu creas un objeto FiltrarMiLista.cs con las propiedades que tu quieres (Marca, Año, Modelo, Tipo) y rellenas las propiedades que tu quieres. Luego creas el componente que al hacer click envia este objeto rellenado al segundo componente.